# How do I change my HDD navigation from Japanese to English?

Tags: toyota, navigation

I have a Toyota 2009 Mark X ZiO trd Sportivo and the model code for my navigation system is  DBA-ANA10 and my car chassis number is ANA10-0030599.

How do I change the language from Japanese to English?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe they can be converted without swapping the navigation system. Might as well hire a translator.